# Financial TimeSeries tohour, to30min,etc

Tags: matlab

In the financial time series toolbox there are a number of methods to convert a base series into daily, weekly, monthly etc...

Are there any functions to convert into 5 minute buckets, 30minutes, hourly etc.... ?

Comment: Not that I know of. You could use a combination of `histc()` and `accumarray()` if the frequency of your data is higher than the desired, e.g. 1min to 5 min, or you can use one of the interpolation functions, e.g. `interp1()`, if you have lower frequency, e.g. 1day to 5 min.

Comment: With histc, I would have to group by day and than assume that my data is continuous through the course of the day.  That is unrealistic.  Ideally there would exist an equivalent of XTS from R.

Comment: "With histc, I would have to group by day and than assume that my data is continuous" both not true.